# UnpicklingError on celerybeat startup

Tags: python, django, celery, supervisord

I've been using supervisord to run celery for my django project for a while, but suddenly celerybeat won't start. It gives the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]celery/apps/beat.py", line 112, in start_scheduler
    beat.start()
  File "[...]celery/beat.py", line 454, in start
    humanize_seconds(self.scheduler.max_interval))
  File "[...]kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 322, in __get__
    value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
  File "[...]celery/beat.py", line 494, in scheduler
    return self.get_scheduler()
  File "[...]celery/beat.py", line 489, in get_scheduler
    lazy=lazy)
  File "[...]celery/utils/imports.py", line 53, in instantiate
    return symbol_by_name(name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "[...]celery/beat.py", line 358, in __init__
    Scheduler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "[...]celery/beat.py", line 185, in __init__
    self.setup_schedule()
  File "[...]celery/beat.py", line 377, in setup_schedule
    self._store['entries']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 122, in __getitem__
    value = Unpickler(f).load()
UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated
```

Haven't been able to find anything on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pieced it together.

The issue was caused by a corrupt `celerybeat-schedule` file. To locate the file enter:

```
find ~/ -name celerybeat-schedule -print
```

Then delete or rename the file:

```
mv [filename] [newfilename]
```

Then restart your processes.